# expect(spiedMethod).not.toBeCalled() fails because it's being called by another test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I've been trying to cover our codebase with tests. I'm using `jest` with [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/).
This is the login method.

```
  public async login(
    @Body() loginDto: DUserLoginRequest,
  ): Promise<DResponse<DLoginResponseV2>> {
    const user: User = await this.userService.verifyCredentials(
      loginDto.login,
      loginDto.password,
    );

    let userTransformed = new DUser(user);
    let accessToken: string = await this.authService.generateUserAccessToken(
      user,
    );

    return new DResponse<DLoginResponseV2>(
      'Successfully logged in',
      new DLoginResponseV2(userTransformed, accessToken),
    );
  }
```

`UserService.verifyCredentials()` throws `UnauthorizedException` if wrong email or password is supplied.

And here is my test cases.

```
  describe('login', () => {
    it('should return user details on successfull login', async () => {
      let loginPayload: DUserLoginRequest = {
        login: 'sayantan.das@codelogicx.com',
        password: 'sayantan94'
      };

      let dUser = new DUser(user);

      let response = new DResponse<DLoginResponseV2>(
        'Successfully logged in',
        new DLoginResponseV2(dUser, 'access_token')
      );

      expect(await userController.login(loginPayload)).toEqual(response);
      expect(userService.verifyCredentials).toBeCalled();
      expect(userService.verifyCredentials).toBeCalledWith(loginPayload.login, loginPayload.password);

      expect(authService.generateUserAccessToken).toBeCalled();
      expect(authService.generateUserAccessToken).toBeCalledWith(user);
      expect(authService.generateUserAccessToken).toReturnWith('access_token');
    });

    it('should throw UnauthorizedException if wrong email or password is provided', async () => {
      let loginPayload = {
        login: 'wrongemail@gamil.com',
        password: 'wrongpassword'
      } as DUserLoginRequest;

      await expect(userController.login(loginPayload)).rejects.toThrow(UnauthorizedException);

      // this assertion fails. but works all right if the successful login test case is removed 
      await expect(authService.generateUserAccessToken).not.toBeCalled();
    });
  });
```

But this test case fails

```
FAIL  src/modules/user/user.controller.spec.ts
  ● User Controller › login › should throw UnauthorizedException if wrong email or password is provided

    expect(jest.fn()).not.toBeCalled()

    Expected mock function not to be called but it was called with:
      [{"country_code": "+91", "email": "sayantan.das@codelogicx.com", "first_name": "Sayantan", "id": 1, "image": "image.url", "last_name": "Das", "password": "$2a$10$.5OelkOKIn9rRuXMsge.yO8tgZdqK8i7PX7knJdjVdqgal7vsky16", "phone_number": "8013220938", "registration_status": "verified"}]

      115 | 
      116 |       await expect(userController.login(loginPayload)).rejects.toThrow(UnauthorizedException);
    > 117 |       await expect(authService.generateUserAccessToken).not.toBeCalled();
          |                                                             ^
      118 |     });
      119 |   });
      120 | });
```

It's failing because the testcase with successful login calls the `generateAccessToken` method. If I remove the successful login test case it works fine. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you clearing mocks between tests?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess not. I set up the mocks in the `beforeAll` hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `beforeAll` hook, in which you setup the mocks and call  `Test.createTestingModule`, to `beforeEach` to create new mocks for every test case, see the example in the [test docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/unit-testing). In most cases you won't notice any performance changes.

Comment: Just noting that an alternative is to use [`mockFn.mockClear`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear) to clear the mocks between tests.